# In short: how do I prove my project coordinator skills in the hiring process?

Tags: career

Some history: I am attempting to transition from one sector of the economy, cultural resource management (a.k.a. contract archaeology), to a more "business-related" sector.  I have spent years within the capacity of a junior and senior project coordinator/assistant manager role, but it has been difficult to translate that experience.  Any advice about certifications that I can get or how to swing my resume.  I want my career path to take me to project management.  Any advice on how to make that happen?  Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2):

A project is a project, whether it's in construction, human resources or IT.
Therefore, focus on the achievements that you got in each of them, accounting the size (budget, scope, resources and schedule) and everything that you did to flawlessly accomplish the proposed objectives, or not, and the reason behind it.

Having that clear understanding will enable you to explain, in a brief amount of time, why you can be a valuable asset to any project or program, regardless the main industry.

Everything else comes after that, you can always train or apply to internships to get experience in specific fields, I would recommend you get PMI's PMP certification as a starting point.

I hope that helps.